# how to manage multiple android emulators in windows?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i'm writing an app on android which will read data from DB or just textfiles, and i'll run it on multiple emulators, each of them has different data.

the question for me is, how can i manage the data in each android emulator `programmatically` on windows?

you may say that DDMS may help, but it's not programmatically(or something i don't know about DDMS?).

so if i write a management program running on windows to handle my question, what tech. should i use, ***telnet***, ***ddms*** or somethingelse? any advise will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address different emulator / device independently by its serial number. The easiest way is to use command line adb.
To see all of your devices and their serial number

```
adb devices
```

To send command to specific device

```
adb -s <serial> <command>
```

For example to push a file to a specific device sdcard

```
adb -s <serial> push <file> /sdcard/
```

More info here
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: thx @roostertech, you gave me a clue to my destination, i'll try it.